# Django saving ManyToManyField gives error: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'str'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm trying to use a ManyToManyField to create a model attribute with a set of options (instances of the m2m model). When I go to save the model in my ModelForm, save_m2m() gives an error saying that Field 'id' expected a number but got 'U'.

Here is my code:

Models:

```
class Choices(models.Model):
description = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Listing(models.Model):
idtag = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
published = models.DateTimeField("Date Published", default=timezone.now)
description = models.TextField()
price = models.PositiveBigIntegerField()
currency = models.ManyToManyField(Choices)
location = models.CharField(max_length=100)
only_location = models.BooleanField(default=False)
tags = TaggableManager()

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('main:listingdetails', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

View:

```
@login_required
def createview(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        creationform = ListingForm(request.POST, author=request.user)
        if creationform.is_valid():
            creationform.save(commit=False)
            creationform.save_m2m()
            listing = creationform.instance
            messages.success(request, "New Listing Created")
            return redirect(reverse('main:listingdetails', kwargs={'pk': listing.idtag}))
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Please correct the error below.')

    creationform = ListingForm
    return render(request,
                "main/createlisting.html",
                context={"creationform":creationform})
```

Form:

```
class ListingForm(forms.ModelForm):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.author = kwargs.pop('author', None)
    super(ListingForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

currencyList = (("USD", "US Dollars"),
    ("GBP", "Pounds"))

currency = forms.ChoiceField(choices=currencyList)

def save(self, commit=True):
        listing = super(ListingForm, self).save(commit=False)
        listing.author = self.author
        if commit:
            listing.save()

class Meta:
    model = Listing
    fields = ('title', 'description', 'price', 'currency', 'tags')
```

Traceback:

```
The above exception (invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'U') was the direct cause of the following exception:

  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)

  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\-\Downloads\zephyrus\main\views.py", line 102, in createview
    creationform.save_m2m()

  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 451, in _save_m2m
    f.save_form_data(self.instance, cleaned_data[f.name])

  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 1668, in save_form_data
    getattr(instance, self.attname).set(data)

  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 1007, in set
    else self.target_field.get_prep_value(obj)

  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 977, in get_prep_value
    return self.target_field.get_prep_value(value)

  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1825, in get_prep_value
    raise e.__class__(


Exception Type: ValueError at /listing/create/

Exception Value: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'U'.
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Yes this is happening as every time a form is submitted, there is no UUID being provided. Django already creates an id number for each entry. You may just want to remove the form field UUID and use default Django ids. Otherwise, you'll have to increment uuid each time a new form is submitted.

Comment: There is a default UUID provided in the model. I have already tested this and it works fine.

Comment: `currency = forms.ChoiceField(choices=currencyList)` -- Shouldn't this be a model choice field with `Choices.objects.all()` as queryset?

Comment: I changed it to that, and still gives same error. Any other ideas?

Comment: In your view, try to manually save the instance returned by `creationform.save(commit=False)` (as you didn't save it yet). So: `instance = creationform.save(commit=False); instance.save(); creationform.save_m2m()`